# Proving A is B if and only if C

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

If a statement says " A is B if and only if C," does that mean the forward direction is: Given A, if B then C and the other direction is Given A, if C then B?

Or does it mean, forward direction is If A is B, then C and backward direction is If C, then A is B?

A more specific example would be: a set with property A has property B if and only if it has property C.

For the forward direction, do I assume we are given a set with property A then suppose it has property B and prove it has property C?

And backward direction: I assume we are given a set with property A and suppose it has property C and prove it has property B?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this depends on what type of objects $A,B$ and $C$ are, but most likely it is the second interpretation. In particular, if $A$ and $B$ are sets and $C$ is a logical statement, then your second interpretation holds; you'd have $(A = B) \Leftrightarrow C$.

If all three of $A,B,C$ are logical formulas, then it is plausible to interpret the statement as $A \Leftrightarrow (B \Leftrightarrow C)$. However, this seems an unlikely interpretation because this would mean that "is" and "if and only if" are both used to mean the equivalence of logical formulas.